# How can I use an expired key with debootstrap?

Tags: debian, debootstrap

I'm trying to use debootstrap to create a Debian Squeeze chroot (from Debian Squeeze (stable)), so I can install some no-longer-supported software. But I get an error:

```
$ sudo debootstrap --keyring=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg squeeze /srv/basket/ http://archive.debian.org/debian/
I: Retrieving InRelease 
I: Retrieving Release 
I: Checking Release signature
E: Release signed by unknown key (key id 64481591B98321F9)
$
```

The key exists, it's just [expired](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=698677):

```
$ gpg --search-keys 64481591B98321F9
gpg: data source: https://18.9.60.141:443
(1)     Squeeze Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>
          4096 bit RSA key 64481591B98321F9, created: 2010-08-07, expires: 2017-08-05 (expired)
Keys 1-1 of 1 for "64481591B98321F9".  Enter number(s), N)ext, or Q)uit >
```

I can proceed by turning off gpg checking with `--no-check-gpg`, but is there a way to tell debootstrap to use the expired key? Or, what is the best way to proceed with as much security as possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you give `debootstrap` the right keyring, it will use the expired key:

```
sudo debootstrap --keyring=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-removed-keys.gpg squeeze /srv/basket/ http://archive.debian.org/debian/
```

An expired key can be used to verify signatures made before it expired.